# How can I pass a Method as a parameter in Android?

Tags: android, methods, parameters

I want to pass a Method (**SaveClound**) as a parameter (**AlertDialog Parameter**) so i can use differents methods through this parameter (**in actionButtons Method**).

```
public void actionButtons(){
    buttonVoltar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog(saveClound());
            // see? I want to call the a method through this parameter
        }
    });
}

public void alertDialog(Method methodName) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builderaction = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builderaction.setTitle("Atenção!");
    builderaction.setMessage("Você tem certeza que deseja sair?");

    builderaction.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // i want to call here the paramater i'm passing on this method (methodName)
                    // so i can call any methods i want right here
                }
            });
    builderaction.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builderaction.create();
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_stop);
    alert.show();
}


public void saveClound(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to pass a method as a parameter, it is not possible natively in Java. There are ways to do it through Interfaces. Check this SO question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter

Comment: I saw it, but i couldn't understand it.. :/

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800711/passing-function-as-a-parameter-in-java/46933426#46933426)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by passing a runnable to the method for example

```
public void actionButtons(){
    buttonVoltar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   saveClound();
               }
            };

            alertDialog(runnable);
        }
    });
}

public void alertDialog(Runnable runnable) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builderaction = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builderaction.setTitle("Atenção!");
    builderaction.setMessage("Você tem certeza que deseja sair?");

    builderaction.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // i want to call here the paramater i'm passing on this method (methodName)
                // so i can call any methods i want right here
                new Handler().post(runnable);
            }
        });
    builderaction.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
   AlertDialog alert = builderaction.create();
   alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_stop);
   alert.show();
}

public void saveClound(){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ABC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```