# AndroidNetworking.post() doesn't wait the response data before returning via string

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronization, android-networking

I have a function inside a aar module that needs to wait the `onResponse()` or `onError()` response by using `AndroidNetworking`. The output is the `return` executes first before waiting on whatever response it will received.  I'm having a problem on waiting the response to return on my app. I also used `synchronized` on the function. this is the code on my module

```
 public static synchronized String getActivationData(final Context context, final String api, final String base64Header, final String endpoint, final JSONObject body) {

    final String[] result = {null};

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


            String baseURL = null;

            if (api.equalsIgnoreCase("LOCAL")) {
                baseURL = Environments.getMarkLocalAPI();
            } else if (api.equalsIgnoreCase("DEVELOPMENT")) {
                baseURL = Environments.getDevelopmentAPI();
            } else if (api.equalsIgnoreCase("STAGING")) {
                baseURL = Environments.getStagingAPI();
            } else if (api.equalsIgnoreCase("DEPLOYMENT")) {
                baseURL = Environments.getDeploymentAPI();
            }

            final String finalBaseURL = baseURL;


            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();

            AndroidNetworking.initialize(context, okHttpClient);

            AndroidNetworking.post(finalBaseURL + endpoint)
                    .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                    .addJSONObjectBody(body)
                    .addHeaders("Project", base64Header)
                    .addHeaders("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .build()
                    .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            result[0] = String.valueOf(response);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(ANError anError) {
                            if (anError.getErrorCode() != 0) {
                                result[0] = String.valueOf(anError.getErrorDetail());

                            } else {
                                result[0] = String.valueOf(anError.getErrorDetail());
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Log.i("data", result[0]);
        }
    }).start();
    return result[0];
}
```

and calling the function on my App via :

```
String data = ActivationResponseV2.getActivationData(getContext(), "LOCAL", header, "/sample/response", jsonObject);
```

may I know what I'm doing wrong?. Thanks!

Comment: You are clearly returning result outside newly created thread which is yet still outside `AndroidNetworking.post` and will definitely fire before post callbacks.

Comment: @GiddyNaya how can i return it inside?. it gives me an error when i put it inside

Comment: Pass a callback to method to consume the value of `result[0]` inside your post call rather than returning it.

Comment: may I get an example? sorry newbie on callback

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46933426/8043806) on passing callbacks to a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by using `ANRequest`. After reading [this](https://amitshekhar.me/Fast-Android-Networking/synchronous_request.html#synchronous-post-request) document. I tried to replicate it and I get my desired output.

This is the code :

```
 public static synchronized String getActivationData(final Context context, final String api, final String base64Header, final String endpoint, final JSONObject body) {

    final String[] result = {null};

    String baseURL = null;

    if (api.equalsIgnoreCase("LOCAL")) {
        baseURL = Environments.getMarkLocalAPI();
    } else if (api.equalsIgnoreCase("DEVELOPMENT")) {
        baseURL = Environments.getDevelopmentAPI();
    } else if (api.equalsIgnoreCase("STAGING")) {
        baseURL = Environments.getStagingAPI();
    } else if (api.equalsIgnoreCase("DEPLOYMENT")) {
        baseURL = Environments.getDeploymentAPI();
    }

    final String finalBaseURL = baseURL;


    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    AndroidNetworking.initialize(context, okHttpClient);

    ANRequest request = AndroidNetworking.post(finalBaseURL + endpoint)
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .addJSONObjectBody(body)
            .addHeaders("Project", base64Header)
            .addHeaders("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build();


    ANResponse response = request.executeForJSONObject();

    if (response.isSuccess()) {
        result[0] = String.valueOf(response.getResult());
        Log.d(TAG, "response : " + result[0]);
    } else {
        ANError error = response.getError();
        Log.d(TAG, "response : " + error);
    }

    return result[0];
    }
}
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Response was returned outside the post call: To handle this you can pass a callback method to your function to consume the result when its ready.

```
public static void getActivationData(final Context context, 
       final String api, final String base64Header, final String endpoint,
         final JSONObject body, Callable<Void> methodParam) { 
            String baseURL = null;

            if (api.equalsIgnoreCase("LOCAL")) {
                baseURL = Environments.getMarkLocalAPI();
            } else if (api.equalsIgnoreCase("DEVELOPMENT")) {
                baseURL = Environments.getDevelopmentAPI();
            } else if (api.equalsIgnoreCase("STAGING")) {
                baseURL = Environments.getStagingAPI();
            } else if (api.equalsIgnoreCase("DEPLOYMENT")) {
                baseURL = Environments.getDeploymentAPI();
            } 


            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();

            AndroidNetworking.initialize(context, okHttpClient);

            AndroidNetworking.post(baseURL + endpoint)
                    .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                    .addJSONObjectBody(body)
                    .addHeaders("Project", base64Header)
                    .addHeaders("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .build()
                    .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            //result[0] = String.valueOf(response);
                            methodParam.call(String.valueOf(response));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(ANError anError) {
                            if (anError.getErrorCode() != 0) {
                               // result[0] = String.valueOf(anError.getErrorDetail()); 
                            } else {
                                //result[0] = String.valueOf(anError.getErrorDetail());
                            }
                            methodParam.call(String.valueOf(anError.getErrorDetail()));
                        }
                    });
             // Log.i("data", result[0]); 
  }
```

Use like below

```
ActivationResponseV2.getActivationData(getContext(), "LOCAL", header, 
           "/sample/response", jsonObject, new Callable<Void>() {
                public Void call(String data) {
                    //...Consume data here
                    return null;
                });
```

Comment: Hi again. as of now, I have tried to put it on my aar. but It prompts a "call() in java.util.concurrent.Callable cannot be applied to java.lang.String"

Comment: Change to `public Void call(String data)`